# website proper redirecting via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I searched about .htaccess redirecting address after first symbol / but I can't get it working.

.htaccess file is like this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldDomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ NewDomain/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OldDomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.NewDomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I test it with the domain

www.OldDomain.com/catalog

its redirects to

www.NewDomain.eucatalog

which does not have the slash symbol **"/"**.

How can I make the redirect keep the slash symbol?

Comment: Hi, I tried to make your question more clear, so you get better help. Welcome to SO by the way! Take a look here to learn more about the website: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thx Hartmann its more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be unrelated, but you need your redirect rules (the last 2) to come **before** your routing rule. It's possible your router (index.php) is redirecting incorrectly:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldDomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ NewDomain/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OldDomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.NewDomain/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: efect is same :( symbol / after domain disapering, second one appears normaly
http://NewDomain.eucatalog/photos

Comment: @EdenLT are you *sure* it's not the `index.php` doing this?

Comment: yeap, i think so, how can i check?

Comment: @EdenLT look at the code for anything that redirects

Comment: no, in index file no any redirect. i thinking, might it possible if:
when redirecting into another site, its read domain-name+category which is writen in wordpress configuration like
http://domain-name.com  (its not contain slash at the and)
and then i gain http://domain-nameslug not /category
or its possible to force htaccess add slash after domain name